# Using Table valued Function in join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, cross-apply

There is a Table valued function which gives multiple rows as output and there are 2 columns as output.

Now I want use this function in the query for all the employees in the employees table

I am using CROSS APPLY but its taking long time and doesn't give any result.

This is the query which I tried

```
select *
from emp A Cross APPLY fnempDiv(A.EmpID)
```

Comment: How many rows in in the `emp` table?  How many rows are returned from `select * from fnempDiv([some EmpID])`?

Comment: You have  to give us the approximate count , or try  with nolock  to check if any other transaction is blocking

Comment: @Kumar if it's blocked, it will still finish and return with rows once the block clears

Comment: @james ther many rows  around 15000

Comment: @kumar there nolock on the tables

Comment: Give us ur tb structure and what u want to get , we will give you the best query

Answer (score 0):

I am using CROSS APPLY

- its taking long time

Unfortunately, that's the nature of CROSS APPLY, since it is a row-by-row operator.  It works great for a few employee rows (convenient) but from what you describe, you should avoid it for this query and expand the query in the APPLY to the outer query.  A simple INNER JOIN should do.

- doesn't give any result.

CROSS APPLY removes `emp A` records that don't produce any rows from the APPLY.  OUTER APPLY will keep the `emp A` records.  If you are getting 0 records overall, you might have passed the wrong column, e.g. `A.EmpID` is not the correct key.

If the function is defined like this (from your comment):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnempDiv(@EmpID)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
 SELECT A.EmpID,D.Name
 FROM empdetail A
 INNER JOIN empdiv D on A.empID=D.ID
 where EXISTS (select * from X)
GO
```

It makes no sense at all. `Select * from X` either fails the entire query or becomes a dud condition, simply by having a record in `X` or otherwise.  The input parameter `@EmpID` is also not being used.

On the other hand, if it is declared as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnempDiv(@EmpID)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
 SELECT A.EmpID,D.Name
 FROM empdetail A
 INNER JOIN empdiv D on A.empID=D.ID
 where A.EmpID = @EmpID
GO
```

Then your full query can be rewritten

```
select E.*, A.emp_ID as EmpDetail_Emp_ID, D.Name
from emp E
INNER JOIN empdetail A ON E.emp_ID=A.EMP_ID
INNER JOIN empdiv D on A.empID=D.ID
```

Moreover, the join `A.empID=D.ID` doesn't even look right.

Comment: Can you show me how can I do this with the help og inner join.

Comment: SELECT A.EmpID,D.Name
 FROM empdetail A INNER JOIN empdiv D on A.empID=D.ID              
 where EXISTS (select * from X)

Comment: What's the `X` table doing here? Do you actually have a table called `X`?